# How to read a TIMESTAMP(6) with time zone data data type on oracle using powershell?

Tags: powershell, oracle11g

I need to read the Oracle table column (which has a datatype TIMESTAMP(6) with time zone) with Powershell or to convert the timestamp datatype to string using Powershell.

Table:

```
select * from job;
```

[image]|

Data type of the table:

```
JOB_id   : Number
DATE     : TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM JOB WHERE JOB_ID=12345"
  $command=$connection.CreateCommand()
  $command.CommandText=$query
  $reader=$command.ExecuteReader()

  while ($reader.Read()) {
      $date=$reader.getInt32(0).ToString() 
      Write-Output $date
  }
```

Error message:

```
 Exception calling "GetString" with "1" argument(s): "Specified cast is
 not valid." At D:\SelfAnalysisKit\job.ps1:765 char:15
 +               $date=$reader.Getstring(2)
 +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastException
```

Comment: a datestamp is neither a int or a string. Likewise, the result of a reader is a `SqlDataReader ` You have some serious data type issues

Comment: if you convert it to a string anyway, you can do it in your sql => `TO_CHAR(DATE , 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF TZH:TZM')`  all you have to do is adjust the format of the date

Answer (score 0):

What value is stored in $reader?
I don't have access to Oracle to test this.
You can pipe your variable to the `Get-Member` cmdlet to see what type of object you have.

```
$reader | Get-Member
```

You can see the value of your object properties by using

```
$reader | Select *
```

If you post the output of those two commands I might be able to help you.

If you look at the methods for SQLDataReader you will see `GetDateTime(Int32)` This may get you closer to your desired out come.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8